# PYTHON search pattern for multiple lines

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am facing issues while trying to fetch my domain name from a big list updated in portal.

```
vser = (login url, password)

for vs in vser:
    if re.match("(^(.*)video(.*)", vs, re.I):
        print(vs.name)
```

my domain name is eg. success.video.com, success.video2.com:80

I used `re.MULTILINE` and `re.DOTALL`, `re.findall` But no luck.

> return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string) TypeError: expected
>   string or buffer

Comment: I see an unbalanced parenthesis in your regex.

Comment: Yes i removed the paranthesis. 

if re.match("^(.*)video(.*)", vs, re.I):


 if re.match("^(.*)video(.*)", vs, re.I):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/re.py", line 156, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: @sai re.match("(^(.*)video(.*))", vs, re.I)

Comment: @Rakesh - I get below error

 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/re.py", line 156, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: I tried using the full domain to check if regex search is working or not success.video.com  but getting same error. Not sure what is wrong 

 return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rakesh - I got it worked after converting the output to strings.

for vs in vser:
    as = str(vs.name)
    if re.match("(^(.*)video(.*)", as, re.I):
    print(as)

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet is working for me.

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016,
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license"
>>> import re
>>> s = "success.video2.com:80"
>>> re.match("(^(.*)video(.*))", s, re.I)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 21), match='success.video2.com:80'>
```

Comment: You are passing it as variable s=success.video2.com . But i am searching it on portal where list of domains available. 

when i click on domains i get abc.example.com; ada.example.com,video.success.com, success.video2.com. 

from these type of list i am trying to fetch domains only have video string.

Comment: Can you post your input? is it a list?

Comment: i get output  in below format

V_sales2_site-80
V_sales2_abc-1099
V_sales2_video-1199
V_sales2_video-1299
V_sales2_amazon-5445